# Email Sent to Mis-configured Data Extension - possible to identify recipients?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

A new client recently sent an email to a Data Extension that they had misconfigured the Send Relationship - they'd mapped the CampaignID to the SubscriberKey (should have been LeadorContactID - DE was filtered from CampaignMember Salesforce data, so CampaignID contained the same value for all records).

The send should have gone to approx 2,000 recipients, but the Tracking log shows it was only sent to 491. Furthermore, all the tracking results are related to a single email address and the SubscriberKey is the CampaignID used in the Filtered DE.

The best path forwards from here would be to identify the people that were sent the email and resend using the original DE (with the SubscriberKey mapping fixed), and using the previous recipients as a suppression list.

Trouble is - as mentioned - the Tracking data shows 491 records all related to a single email address and subscriberkey. After 9 days 'help' from Marketing Cloud support they informed me that there is nowhere in the system that the actual send information required can be extracted from.

I find this very hard to believe and it certainly wouldn't be the first time MC support has given me information that turned out to be not quite accurate.

Does anyone know of a location that records the actual emails sent and the addresses they are sent to? And any ideas on why the email sent to 491 people out of the 2000? The tracking data (opens, clicks etc) suggests it really did send to this number of people, despite the tracking showing just a single email & subscriberkey.

Thanks everyone for any input

Matt

Comment: Do you have a sendlog dataextension? if not the _sent dataview will be the best option for you in conjunction with the job dataview (joining them).

Answer (score 0):

The emailaddress sent to is not recorded anywhere, and the emailaddress on the All subs is the reference. Since all subs was updated which each batch and deduped (why only 491 were sent out of 2000)

So unless you used a sendlog like Johannes outlined that recorded emailaddress at send time, there is not a way to reconcile this.